# How to authenticate users with Slack Direct Install URLs if they aren’t logged in to my application?

Tags: oauth-2.0, slack-api

Slack provides the ability to make a [Direct Install](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#make_installation_more_direct) to install your application.

> When you save your Direct Install URL, Slack will attempt to send a simple HTTP GET request to your declared URL. If it doesn't detect a HTTP 302 redirect pointing back to a fully qualified slack.com/oauth/authorize URL (see below), you'll receive an error letting you know.
>
> ...
>
> First Slack sends the user to your Direct Install URL:
>
> ```
> GET /slack/direct_install HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> ```
>
> Then your server kindly redirects back to Slack's OAuth 2.0 authorization page:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=12345.67890&scope=channels%3Ahistory%20users%3Aread&state=abcdefg
> ```
>
> Resulting in the user jumping right into authorization. One point of friction removed.
>
> You may continue to generate your own time or context sensitive state parameters and specific, pre-registered redirect_uri values as needed.

How does this integrate with my own apps user authentication? As I read it, the Direct Install URL must always 302 redirect to the Slack OAuth page. If the user *isn't* logged in to my application when they click the "Install" button, what am I meant to do?

My best guess is that I should:

1. Always redirect to the Slack OAuth URL and generate a state parameter to keep track of the request.
2. When the user finishes their authentication, they are redirected back with the `code` and `state` parameters.
3. If they aren't logged in, ask them to log in, and retain the OAuth `code` and `state` parameters. Once the user logs in, continue with the OAuth authentication process.

Is that right? Is there a way to force the user to be signed in to my app before trying to install the Slack app?

On a security note, for this to work with session cookies, I think they would need to be set to SameSite=lax, not =strict. The cookie wouldn't be passed from a cross domain request when they are set to strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of options:

**1) Don't use it.**

The "Direct install" feature is a shortcut to the standard "Slack Button" installation process. Since in your case the user needs to first log into your app anyways, I think it would be more user friendly to also provide the Slack button in the same context on your webpage.

**2) Return an error**

If you detect that the user is not logged into your app, you could just return an error to Slack, e.g. http code 500. Slack should then also return an error to the user (not sure how it looks though). If you combine that with a clear message on your Slack App install page about the requirement to first login to your app that could work. This would be the easiest to implement, but also the least user friendly approach.

**3) Request login to app after Slack login**

After you completed the Oauth process and recognize that the user is not logged into your app you could request the user to login to complete the installation process. The disadvantage here is that your app would already be installed and could be left in an unusable state if the user failed to login at this point.

**4) Halt Oauth process for user login**

As you suggested you could halt the Oauth process after receiving the authorization code and request a user login to your app. Then continue the Oauth process after a successful user login. This can work if you need to take into account that the authorization code will expire after 10 mins. I do not see any way of forcing the user to login before he clicks on the direct install button.

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question, I’m talking about whether the user is logged in to my application, not Slack.

Comment: ah. that changes things

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your clarification

Comment: Those options all make sense. I don't know if 2 would work, because Slack itself verifies that a 302 is sent when they request the install link from their servers, but the other ones all seem like good options. I think step 4 is probably the most correct, but also the most work!